# Strange Characters coming out of my Base 64 Decoder?

Tags: c, encoding, base64, decode

Hi I wrote a base 64 encoder/decoder. My encoder works perfect, so I tried to do in reverse to get my decoder. I get most of the characters right, but I get strange characters. For example if I decode the encoded 'Man is' I get 'Man i}' or the encoded 'I like to eat food' gives me 'I like t eat fo?|4?'. Im not sure where these characters are coming from. Here is the code to my decoder.

```
int b64_decode(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
    do {
        char outbuf [57+3];// room for null \n \r
        for(int i=0; i < sizeof(outbuf);i++) //filling
            outbuf[i]=0;

        char inbuf [76];//ratio 3ascii/4chars
        for(int i=0; i < sizeof(inbuf);i++)//filling
            inbuf[i]=0;

        int i1;
        int i2;
        int i3;
        int i4;
        int o1;
        int o2;
        int o3;
        int combine;
        size_t read_cnt;
        read_cnt = fread(inbuf,1,sizeof(inbuf),in);
        for (int i = 0; i < read_cnt; i=i+4)
        {   
            i1=inbuf[i];
            i2=inbuf[i+1];
            i3=inbuf[i+2];
            i4=inbuf[i+3];

            for (int i =0; i < sizeof(ENCODE); i++)
            {
                if((int)ENCODE[i]==i1)
                    i1=i;
                if((int)ENCODE[i]==i2)
                    i2=i;
                if((int)ENCODE[i]==i3)
                    i3=i;
                if((int)ENCODE[i]==i4)
                    i4=i;
            }

            i3 = i3 <<6;
            i2 = i2 << 12;
            i1 = i1 << 18;
            combine = i1+i2+i3+i4;
            o3 = (combine & 0xff);
            combine = combine >> 8;
            o2 = (combine & 0xff);
            combine = combine >> 8;
            o1 = (combine & 0xff);

            outbuf[i*3/4]=(char)o1;
            outbuf[i*3/4+1]=(char)o2;
            outbuf[i*3/4+2]=(char)o3;
            if(inbuf[i*(3/4)]=='=')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+1]=='=')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)+1]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=='=')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=='=')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=' ';

            if(inbuf[i*(3/4)]=='\n')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+1]=='\n')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)+1]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=='\n')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=='\n')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=' ';
            if(inbuf[i*(3/4)]=='\r')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+1]=='\r')
                outbuf[i*(3/4)+1]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=='\r')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+2]=' ';
            if(inbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=='\r')
                outbuf[(3/4)*i+3]=' ';
        }

        for(int i=0; i < sizeof(outbuf);i++)
        {
            if(outbuf[i]==0)
            {
                outbuf[i+2]='\0';
                outbuf[i]='\r';
                outbuf[i+1]='\n';
                i=sizeof(outbuf);
            }
        }

        printf("%s",outbuf);

    } while(feof(in)==0);

    return 0;
}
```

To sum it up, Im taking the 4 characters from the encoder, finding their value in my array ENCODE (so reversing it) and setting them equal to their position. Then I combine them into a 32 bit number, take the 3 8 bit numbers and print out those 3 characters. I made checks for if its =, \n, \r. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: You might want to substitute your fread with fgets. Right now you're reading the \n EOLs as well and feed them into your decoder.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Actually, `fgets()` doesnt strip them either. The difference is that fgets will feed you the input line-by-line.

Comment: Of course. Thank you. It's too late this evening. Anyway, his code decodes the \n's which is wrong.

Comment: well I deleted that whole section with the /n and /r decoding and I still end up with the same random characters